# how to use paramiko ssh object to send remote calls to Windows and Linux server?

Tags: python, linux, windows, paramiko

I am using Python 2.7.6 and Paramiko module (on a Linux server) to connect to a Windows server and send some commands and get output. I have a connect function which takes IP, username and password of the remote Windows server and I get an sshobj when that happens. How do I use it to send remote calls is my question?

If it were a local system, I would just say "os.system" but not sure about the remote calls. Can someone help?

My code looks like below:
    sys.path.append("/home/me/code")

```
import libs.ssh_connect as ssh
ssh_obj = ssh.new_conn(IP, username, password)

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_obj.exec_command("dir") #since the remote    system I am SSHing into is Windows.
```

my "new_conn" looks like this:

```
import paramiko
def new_conn(IP, username, password):
    ssh_obj = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh_conn.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh_conn.connect(IP, username, password), timeout=30)
    return ssh_obj
```

All I get from stdin, stdout and stderror is "active; 1 open channel anhd some bunch of info like ChannelFile, aes, etc..).

I was hoping to see the output of "dir" from Windows on my Linux..

tried "stdout.read()" and "stdout.readlines()" but the former came out with "stdout" and the latter came out with "[]"!

Thanks!

Comment: JFYI - I am executing the above code on a Linux server and send them across to a Windows server .. hence the usage of "dir" command. I would like to process them back on the Linux server though..

Comment: if I replaced "dir" with "ipconfig" it works fine. I wonder how I can make "dir" work..

Answer (score 2):

I installed FreeSSHd on my Windows, and it works!

FreeSSHd Tutorial: (Chinese)
https://jingyan.baidu.com/article/f7ff0bfc1ebd322e27bb1344.html

Code:(Python 3)

```
import paramiko

hostname = "windows-hostname"
username = "windows-username"
password = "windows-password"

cmd = 'ifconfig'
try:
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(hostname,username=username,password=password)
    print("Connected to %s" % hostname)
except paramiko.AuthenticationException:
    print("Failed to connect to %s due to wrong username/password" %hostname)
    exit(1)
except Exception as e:
    print(e.message)    
    exit(2)

try:
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd)
except Exception as e:
    print(e.message)

err = ''.join(stderr.readlines())
out = ''.join(stdout.readlines())
final_output = str(out)+str(err)
print(final_output)
```

Comment: FreeSSHd probably shouldn't be used if security is a concern. It hasn't been maintained in a years and it's current version (1.3.1) has a known vulnerability (CVE-2018-9853) 
https://medium.com/@TheWindowsTwin/vulnerability-in-freesshd-5a0abc147d7a

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `cmd.exe /c` before `dir` as `cmd.exe /c dir` to be able to run commands remotely on Windows.

Stick to exec_command and do not try send/recv commands. I never got send/recv commands to work with Windows, at least with the SSH server I am using with windows (FreeSSHd).

Answer (score 1):

Last windows versions have built-in SSH client/server see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse)